# How to get random words for Array List?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a hangman project. For right now, I have a list of words in a TXT file. I have a `RandomString` class that I need to use. I am working on the `Next` method and am stuck. Here's what I have:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomString {
    private String filename;
    private ArrayList<String> phrases;

    public RandomString(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
        reset();
    }

    public void reset() {
        phrases = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            while (scan.hasNext()) 
                phrases.add(scan.nextLine());
            scan.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }

    public String next() {
        if (phrases.isEmpty())
            reset();
    }
}
```

My next method needs to: see if the ArrayList is empty and if it is reset, then get a random number between 0 and the size of your list, then get the item, then remove the item, and then return the item.

Comment: what exact problem do you have? you cannot get a random number? cannot get the item? cannot remove the item? cannot return it?

Comment: You have a lot of questions here, try to narrow the scope

Comment: And the code you posted for next is completely empty? You can't expect fill-in-the-blanks answers here. You need to show some effort at solving your problem _especially_ if it is homework.

Comment: There's not much to go on here, can I suggest showing us more of what you tried in the `Next()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Getting  the random number: `Math.Random` cast to `int` and multiply by how ever many items are in your list and 10.

Eg.

- 6 items in your list, `int abc=(int) (Math.random()*60);`
- 4 items, `int abc=(int) (Math.random()*40);`

but I don't understand the rest of your question

or you can use the `java.util.random`

Comment: The `Random` class has methods for integer ranged randoms. Probably they're doing the same, but it's just one less source of errors.

Answer (score 1):

My first intension is to comment on your coding style. It is bad so make sure to put comments if necessary specially when asking something from others.

Other thing is make/post something complete, eg. blocks like if | else statements with closing and opening brackets.

I guess that you need to randomly get items from the array list based on its content. If so you can get an idea about how to do that. This code will be going to content of your uncompleted else condition.

Here the answer for your question, please follow some common standards used here to make your code more understandable (regardless of where you write - in company, in a post, in a blog etc).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomString {
    private String filename;
    private ArrayList<String> phrases;
    // Random number generator instance
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    public RandomString(String filename)

    {
        this.filename = filename;
        reset();
    }

    public void reset() {
        phrases = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            while (scan.hasNext())
                phrases.add(scan.nextLine());
            scan.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public String next() {

        // Value retrieved from array-list
        String item = null;
        // Index to be read from array-list
        int index = 0;

        // Reset the array-list if is it empty
        if (phrases.isEmpty()) {
            reset();
        }

        // Check the size, there is a possibility to have zero elements in your stored file
        if (phrases.size() > 0) {

            if (phrases.size() > 1) {
                // Get a random number
                index = randomGenerator.nextInt(phrases.size());
            } else {
                // If the array-list has only one item there is no need to get a random number.
                index = 0;
            }
            // Get the indexed item
            item = phrases.get(index);
            // Remove item
            phrases.remove(index);

        }

        // Return the item
        return item;
    }
}
```

So do your best.